# Xcode/Cocoa ARC and MRC classes. Would MRC autoreleases cause memory leaks in an ARC class?

Tags: cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, autorelease

I'm working on a Cocoa App. Most of the app is ARC, but I'm using a version of the Amazon SDK for iOS which is MRC. (I've made only a few updates to the amazon classes so it works with Cocoa).

I've disabled ARC for all of amazon's files I'm using with -fno-objc-arc.

If I use one of the MRC classes from Amazon SDK in one of my ARC classes. Do I need to surround it with an @autorelease?

I'm experiencing memory leaks from Amazon classes and have not been able to get to the source of it.

For example. Let's say the MRC class is this: (this is very contrived to simplify what I'm asking):

```
@implementation MyMRCClass
- (void) doStuff {
    NSArray * tmp = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
}
@end
```

Then let's say I use that class somewhere in ARC:

```
@implementation MyARCClass
- (void) doSomethingWithMyClass {
    [self.myClass doStuff];
}
@end
```

Do I need to wrap calls to MyMRCClass with @autorelease?

```
@implementation MyARCClass
- (void) doSomethingWithMyClass {
    @autorelease {
        [self.myClass doStuff];
    }
}
```

@end

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `@autorelease` unless it is the entry point of a new thread. The autorelease pool on main thread should be created for you in your main function.

As long as you have balanced `retain`/`release` and correct naming conversion, and no retain cycle, it should be fine.

MRC doesn't change anything if you do it correctly, it should behave just like ARC.

Read [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047-CJBFBEDI) for when to use it.